# What is English equivalent to 座右の銘 – a motto you always keep by the side?

Tags: phrases

I was interested in a word, “*Refrigerator magnet maxim*,” which I recently found in an article of some newspaper (I forgot what it was), and then quotes in google.

We have the word, 座右の銘 - zayu-no-mei, of which literal translation is a motto that you always keep by the side and ruminate over once a day. I understand Chinese have the similar word, 座右銘-zuoyoumin. For instance, 塞翁が馬 - Life is like Old Sai’s horse” is my motto that I keep by the side, and I use to tell myself whenever things don’t go as I wish.

I think 座右の銘 / 座右銘 have more serious tone and provide a practical suggestion to serve as a guideline in your daily life than a simple motto or maxim that comes into your mind from time to time, or “refrigerator magnet maxim” you casually glance at.

I’m looking for English equivalent to 座右の銘. What are they?

Comment: Well there's the idiom "Words to live by".  And several others.

Comment: And some people will use "personal mantra" to identify a catchphrase they reference repeatedly,

Comment: A "watchword"..

Comment: What's wrong with *motto*? Unless there is something special about "always keep by the side", in which case your question is unclear, one's motto seems to be exactly what you describe. IOW, what on Earth do you mean by a motto that "**you always keep by the side**"?

Comment: Brief description of Old Sai's horse: http://www.yellowbridge.com/literature/horse.php

Comment: @Drew.I think you can have as many number of mottos corresponding to different aspects of your life as you like, e,g, Your way of life – be kind to others, Doing business – keep your promise / due date even if  your mom dies, Controlling your health: don’t forget to take minimum1 hour strained exercise every day regardless heat, rain or snow, Social contact: be honest, keep smile always. Money: don’t’ spend more than you earn. Failure: don’t cry over the spilt milk. Wherereas, 座右の銘 is the most important, single motto or the very basic guideline you chose from among a bunch of mottos or maxims

Comment: Continued: as the most fitting to your need and keep (literally - 座右）on your side  24 hours / 7days all through your entire life.

Comment: @HotLicks *Mantra* sounds like an answer (with appropriate links and definition). After posting my answer, this occurred to me, and I planned to add it to my post next chance I got. Lo, and behold, you are already there!

Comment: @bib - Be my guest!

Comment: @Hot Licks. I think ' Personal mantra' fits to the concept of 座右の銘 very well as well as bib's 'daily affirmation,' which I accepted, because the idea of 座右  (zayu) is 'personal, only your own' and "always beside you (in your head)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a concept of *daily affirmations*. An internet search will turn up hundreds of sites offering these sayings.

While many people in the US seem to subscribe to a regular consultation with these aphorisms, the term is often used sarcastically as exemplified by the *Saturday Night Live* character, [Stuart Smalley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Smalley) (played by Al Franken, who has gone on to become the US Senator from Minnesota).

As an example of the positive effects of his philosophical contemplations, he ended every skit by looking into a mirror and telling himself *You're good enough, you're smart enough, and, doggone it, people like you!*

Answer (score 3):

I would say ***favorite motto*** or ***personal motto***.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the word [maxim](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maxim), which oxfordictionaries.com defines as

> A short, pithy statement expressing a general truth or rule of conduct.

Answer (score 1):

An [aphorism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aphorism) may fit your description:

> - a terse saying embodying a general truth or astute observation, as “Art is long, life is short.”

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Motto seems to be the word, but the noun (favorite) [***byword***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/byword) could be considered.

> A word or expression summarizing a thing’s characteristics or a
>   person’s principles: *Small is beautiful’ may be the byword for most couturiers*

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> a proverbial saying: proverb, a frequently used word or phrase: *Mom's favorite byword is “You can get more flies with honey than with vinegar”*.

[[Merriam-Webster]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/byword)